# Android Database: Alternate database for different locale?

Tags: android, sqlite

I am trying to create localized versions of my application. The [Localization](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/resources/localization.html) article doesn't help me much, since it refers only to xml resources. How can I tell the app to use a different database for each locale?

I am assuming it has something to do with the `android_metadata` table that is required for each Android database, but I have yet to find a good explanation of how to go about this.

Comment: why do you need a separate database?

Comment: he might not need a different database if that is not required but his question might be 'how to support data for different languages' Sometimes it is convenient to just use different languages. Or he might be having his data for each language in a separate database.

Comment: There's really nothing stopping me from using a single database. In fact, it might be easier to do that. So thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Call `getResources().getConfiguration().getLocale()` to get a `Locale` object. Use that to get the language (and variant) if needed, for use in a column or a table or a database filename.

Comment: @Taka: Among other things, I believe that is where Android puts the schema revision number, as used by `SQLiteOpenHelper`.